# Python Pong Collision Is Uncooperative

Tags: python, collision, turtle-graphics, python-turtle, pong

I'm making a pong game in Python but the ball is not colliding with either paddle. I've found similar questions, yet none of them seem to work. At random points, the ball seems to slow down, but I can't correlate it to anything relevant, unless it's a case of misplaced hitboxes, in which case I can't seem to spot the outlier.

Code:

```
import os
import turtle as t

playerAscore = 0
playerBscore = 0

window = t.Screen()
window.title('Game of pongs the pong game pong the game game the pong pong pong pong the EmAG')
window.bgcolor('black')
window.setup(width=800, height=600)
window.tracer(0)


leftpaddle = t.Turtle()
leftpaddle.speed(0)
leftpaddle.shape('square')
leftpaddle.color('white')
leftpaddle.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
leftpaddle.penup()
leftpaddle.goto(-270, 0)


rightpaddle = t.Turtle()
rightpaddle.speed(0)
rightpaddle.shape('square')
rightpaddle.color('purple')
rightpaddle.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
rightpaddle.penup()
rightpaddle.goto(270, 0)


ball = t.Turtle()
ball.speed(0)
ball.shape('circle')
ball.color('red')
ball.penup()
ball.goto(1, 1)
ball_dx = 0.1
ball_dy = 0.1


pen = t.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.color('Pink')
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(0, 260)
pen.write('Score', align='center', font=('Shadows into Light', 24, 'normal'))



def leftpaddleup():
    y = leftpaddle.ycor()
    y = y + 90
    leftpaddle.sety(y)


def leftpaddledown():
    y = leftpaddle.ycor()
    y = y + -90
    leftpaddle.sety(y)



def rightpaddleup():
    y = rightpaddle.ycor()
    y = y + 90
    rightpaddle.sety(y)


def rightpaddledown():
    y = rightpaddle.ycor()
    y = y + -90
    rightpaddle.sety(y)



window.listen()
window.onkeypress(leftpaddleup, 'w')
window.onkeypress(leftpaddledown, 's')
window.onkeypress(rightpaddleup, 'Up')
window.onkeypress(rightpaddledown, 'Down')

while True:
    window.update()

    # mover of balls
    ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball_dx)
    ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ball_dy)

    if ball.ycor() > 290:
        ball.sety(290)
    ball_dy = ball_dy * -1
    if ball.ycor() < -290:
        ball.sety(-290)
    ball_dy = ball_dy * -1

    if ball.xcor() > 390:
        ball.goto(0, 0)
        ball_dx = ball_dx * -1

        os.system("afplay wallhit.wav&")
    if (ball.xcor()) < -390:  # Left width paddle Border
        ball.goto(0, 0)
        ball_dx = ball_dx * -1

        os.system("afplay wallhit.wav&")

    # paddle collision

    if (ball.xcor() < -340) and (ball.xcor() > -350) and (
            paddle_right.ycor() + 40 > ball.ycor() > paddle_right.ycor() - 40):
        ball.setx(-340)
        ball_dx = ball_dx * -1
        os.system("afplay paddle.wav&")

    if (ball.xcor() < 340) and (not ball.xcor() <= 350) and (
            paddle_left.ycor() + 0 > ball.ycor() > paddle_left.ycor() - 350):
        ball.setx(340)
        ball_dx = ball_dx * -1
        os.system("afplay paddle.wav&")
```

Comment: `(ball.xcor() > -340) and (ball.xcor() < -350)` can never be true - reverse the two constants, or the two comparison operators.

Comment: ball still goes through

Comment: This same "original" code gets posted to [turtle-graphics] and [python-turtle] over and over again.  And no one ever cites the actual source, which might help.

Answer (score 0):

This code is typical of the problems you're having:

```
    if (ball.xcor() < -340) and (ball.xcor() > -350) and (
            paddle_right.ycor() + 40 > ball.ycor() > paddle_right.ycor() - 40):
        ball.setx(-340)
        ball_dx = ball_dx * -1
        #...

    if (ball.xcor() < 340) and (not ball.xcor() <= 350) and (
            paddle_left.ycor() + 0 > ball.ycor() > paddle_left.ycor() - 350):
        ball.setx(340)
        #...
```

First, the left paddle is being treated completely different than the right paddle -- the right paddle logic makes no sense.  Next, you're checking the ball against the left paddle's X position, but using the right paddle's Y position!?!  And vice versa.  Next, you're testing -350 < x < -340 but the left paddle is at x == -270 and the ball, and paddle, are 20 pixels wide!?!  So, we'd expect the test to be more like -270 < x < -250 or some such.

Finally, the above code refers to `paddle_right` and `paddle_left` which don't exist -- in the rest of your program they are called `rightpaddle` and `leftpaddle`.  If you actually got a paddle collision, your code would crash.

Below is a complete rewrite of your code, using constants to hold the various fixed parameters and doing the math to describe where things are.  It's also been rearranged to be a valid event-based turtle program (no `while True:` allowed).  And a bunch of other stuff:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

FONT = ('Arial', 24, 'normal')

SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT = 800, 600

LEFT_PADDLE_X = -300
RIGHT_PADDLE_X = 300

PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_HEIGHT = 20, 100
PADDLE_HALF_HEIGHT = PADDLE_HEIGHT/2

BALL_DIAMETER = 20
BALL_RADIUS = BALL_DIAMETER/2

SCREEN_LEFT_MARGIN = BALL_DIAMETER - SCREEN_WIDTH/2
SCREEN_RIGHT_MARGIN = SCREEN_WIDTH/2 - BALL_DIAMETER
SCREEN_TOP_MARGIN = SCREEN_HEIGHT/2 - BALL_DIAMETER
SCREEN_BOTTOM_MARGIN = BALL_DIAMETER - SCREEN_HEIGHT/2

LEFT_PADDLE_SURFACE = LEFT_PADDLE_X + PADDLE_WIDTH/2
RIGHT_PADDLE_SURFACE = RIGHT_PADDLE_X - PADDLE_WIDTH/2

PADDLE_SHIFT = PADDLE_HEIGHT - BALL_RADIUS

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

def paddle_leftup():
    paddle_left.forward(PADDLE_SHIFT)
    screen.update()

def paddle_leftdown():
    paddle_left.backward(PADDLE_SHIFT)
    screen.update()

def paddle_rightup():
    paddle_right.forward(PADDLE_SHIFT)
    screen.update()

def paddle_rightdown():
    paddle_right.backward(PADDLE_SHIFT)
    screen.update()

left_score = 0
right_score = 0

ball_dx = 2
ball_dy = 2

def move_ball():
    global left_score, right_score, ball_dx, ball_dy

    x, y = ball.position()

    x += ball_dx
    y += ball_dy

    if  x < SCREEN_LEFT_MARGIN:
        x, y = 0, 0
        ball_dx *= -1
        right_score += 1
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("Score: {}, {}".format(left_score, right_score), align='center', font=FONT)
    elif x > SCREEN_RIGHT_MARGIN:
        x, y = 0, 0
        ball_dx *= -1
        left_score += 1
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("Score: {}, {}".format(left_score, right_score), align='center', font=FONT)
    else:
        if y > SCREEN_TOP_MARGIN:
            y = SCREEN_TOP_MARGIN
            ball_dy *= -1
        elif y < SCREEN_BOTTOM_MARGIN:
            y = SCREEN_BOTTOM_MARGIN
            ball_dy *= -1

        # paddle collision

        left_y, right_y = paddle_left.ycor(), paddle_right.ycor()

        if LEFT_PADDLE_SURFACE - BALL_RADIUS/2 < x < LEFT_PADDLE_SURFACE + BALL_RADIUS:
            if left_y - PADDLE_HALF_HEIGHT < y < left_y + PADDLE_HALF_HEIGHT:
                ball_dx *= -1
                ball.setx(LEFT_PADDLE_SURFACE + ball_dx)
        elif RIGHT_PADDLE_SURFACE - BALL_RADIUS < x < RIGHT_PADDLE_SURFACE + BALL_RADIUS/2:
            if right_y - PADDLE_HALF_HEIGHT < y < right_y + PADDLE_HALF_HEIGHT:
                ball_dx *= -1
                ball.setx(RIGHT_PADDLE_SURFACE + ball_dx)

    ball.setposition(x, y)

    screen.update()
    screen.ontimer(move_ball)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
screen.title("Game of pong")
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.tracer(0)

paddle_left = Turtle()
paddle_left.speed('fastest')
paddle_left.shape('square')
paddle_left.shapesize(stretch_len=PADDLE_HEIGHT/CURSOR_SIZE, stretch_wid=PADDLE_WIDTH/CURSOR_SIZE)
paddle_left.color('white')
paddle_left.penup()
paddle_left.setheading(90)
paddle_left.setx(LEFT_PADDLE_X)

paddle_right = paddle_left.clone()
paddle_right.color('purple')
paddle_right.setx(RIGHT_PADDLE_X)

ball = Turtle()
ball.speed('fastest')
ball.shape('circle')
ball.color('red')
ball.penup()

pen = Turtle()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.speed('fastest')
pen.color('Pink')
pen.penup()
pen.sety(260)
pen.write('Score: {}, {}'.format(left_score, right_score), align='center', font=FONT)

screen.onkeypress(paddle_leftup, 'w')
screen.onkeypress(paddle_leftdown, 's')
screen.onkeypress(paddle_rightup, 'Up')
screen.onkeypress(paddle_rightdown, 'Down')
screen.listen()

move_ball()

screen.mainloop()
```

Not perfect, but should give you something that's basically working that you can build upon and tweak.